# AngularJS 1.x - $scope inspections shows $scope.data but direct access to $scope.data == undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am watching $scope.taskId and then trying to access a property on $scope.data.

Here's my function:

```
$scope.$watch('taskId', function(value) {
    console.log('here---------------');
    console.log($scope, $scope.data);
    var titlePrefix = undefined;
    if (value) {
        titlePrefix = $scope.getTaskTitlePrefix();
        Page.setTitle(titlePrefix + $scope.taskId);
        $scope.loadData();
    }
});
```

I am logging $scope and $scope.data above in line 3.

**(console.log($scope, $scope.data);)**

Here's the output in the console:

> here---------------
>
> m {$$childTail: m, $$childHead: b, $$nextSibling: m, $$watchers: 
>   Array(81), $$listeners: Object…}
>
> undefined

Any ideas why $scope seems to be ready and available but its variables are not??

This is the HTML where the taskId variable is initialised and as you can see there is a whole lot going on here. This is a major Laravel and Angular application with more than 2700 pages without including vendor or node folders (1700+ Laravel, 1000+ angular)

```
<div ng-controller="TasksCtrl" ng-init="taskId = '{!! $task->id !!}'" ng-cloak>
    <span ng-init="severities = {{ json_encode($severities) }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="statuses = {{ $statuses }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="users = {{ $users }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="subtypes = {{ App\Modules\Bookings\TaskSubtype::support()->get() }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="standard_prices = {{ StandardPrice::all() }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="shelf_types = {{ json_encode(App\Modules\Bookings\Task::getShelfTypes()) }}"></span>
```

That is an excerpt from tasks.blade.php file which is the content section of the page.

The actual title is used in layouts.blade.php and it actually sets the title of the browser tab and **NOT** the title of any "on page" heading.

```
>head<

>meta charset="utf-8"<
>meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"<

<title ng-controller="TitleController" ng-cloak>{[{ Page.getTitle() }]}</title>
```

This is the getTitle function that is called into play when the taskId changes.

```
archDB.factory('Page', function () {
    var title = 'Seraph';
    return {
        getTitle: function() { return title; },
        setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle; }
    };
});
```

And here's the $scope.data variable part of the $scope inspection from the browser console to give a sense of scale.

> data: m
>   $promise
>   :
>   d
>   $resolved
>   :
>   true
>   alarm_date
>   :
>   null
>   antivirus_state
>   :
>   null
>   assigned_to
>   :
>   104
>   attended_time
>   :
>   0
>   auto_booked
>   :
>   1
>   booking_fee
>   :
>   null
>   booking_fee_id
>   :
>   null
>   builds
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   cancelled_reason
>   :
>   null
>   client
>   :
>   Object
>   client_id
>   :
>   53
>   client_type
>   :
>   "client"
>   collected_at
>   :
>   null
>   completed
>   :
>   0
>   completed_at
>   :
>   null
>   created_at
>   :
>   "2016-12-07 11:23:03"
>   created_by
>   :
>   16
>   creator
>   :
>   Object
>   customer_notifications
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   deleted_at
>   :
>   null
>   delivered
>   :
>   0
>   delivered_by
>   :
>   null
>   devices
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   direct_dial
>   :
>   null
>   due_date
>   :
>   null
>   exchange_id
>   :
>   null
>   feedback
>   :
>   null
>   followup_id
>   :
>   null
>   formatedAttendedTime
>   :
>   ""
>   formatedUnattendedTime
>   :
>   ""
>   id
>   :
>   84222
>   invoice_number
>   :
>   null
>   invoiced
>   :
>   0
>   invoiced_at
>   :
>   null
>   invoiced_by_project
>   :
>   0
>   labour
>   :
>   0
>   modifier
>   :
>   Object
>   needs_calling
>   :
>   0
>   needs_delivery
>   :
>   null
>   no_price_reason
>   :
>   null
>   nopassword_reason
>   :
>   null
>   onsite_end
>   :
>   "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
>   onsite_start
>   :
>   "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
>   order_task_id
>   :
>   null
>   paid
>   :
>   0
>   paid_at
>   :
>   "2016-12-07"
>   parts
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   parts_total
>   :
>   0
>   passed_qa
>   :
>   null
>   passwords
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   pin
>   :
>   null
>   points
>   :
>   0
>   prebook
>   :
>   0
>   prebook_date
>   :
>   "01-01-1970"
>   problem
>   :
>   " **removed**"
>   project_id
>   :
>   null
>   qa_id
>   :
>   null
>   qa_tasks
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   related_tasks
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   return_id
>   :
>   null
>   revision_history
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   satisfied_client
>   :
>   null
>   seraph_id
>   :
>   null
>   severity_id
>   :
>   2
>   shelf
>   :
>   null
>   shelf_type
>   :
>   null
>   site
>   :
>   Object
>   site_id
>   :
>   53
>   site_user
>   :
>   Object
>   site_user_id
>   :
>   535
>   standard_price
>   :
>   null
>   standard_price_id
>   :
>   null
>   status
>   :
>   Object
>   status_id
>   :
>   1
>   subscribed_user
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   subscribers
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   subtype_id
>   :
>   1
>   template_items
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   templates
>   :
>   Array(0)
>   time_spent
>   :
>   0
>   title
>   :
>   "For Nadeem"
>   type
>   :
>   "support"
>   unattended_time
>   :
>   0
>   updated_at
>   :
>   "2016-12-07 11:24:04"
>   updated_by
>   :
>   94
>   user
>   :
>   Object

---------------- edit 00.14 -----------------

Here's a loadData function that makes an ajax call to the laravel api and the response gets assigned to $scope.data there

```
$scope.loadData = function() {
    Tasks.get({taskId: $scope.taskId}, function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
        $scope.modified = false;
        CustomerNotificationsService.setNotifications(response.customer_notifications);
        $ClientsManager.setClient(response.client);
        $ClientsManager.setClientType(response.client_type);
        $scope.registerWatchers();
    }, ErrorsHandler);
};
```

Comment: All scope watchers are executed once, but scope is not ready yet. (Look at this as kind of initializing..) If you watch ```data``` on your scope and set a breakpoint into the watcher, then the first run will be with an undefined value, but the second time data should be filled completely.

Comment: when/where are you assigning the $scope.data?

Comment: @angabriel - how do you set a breakpoint and how do you know when $scope.data is ready?

Comment: @Kossel $scope.data and it's sub properties are distributed throughout tasks.blade.php - using atom i searched for data and it counted 224 times!

Comment: @OP: look here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/, the second point "Pause the code with a breakpoint".

Comment: @angabriel - sorry I didn't realise you meant in the browser dev tools breakpoint, I know how to do that but that doesn't help fix the code. Can you explain why when I log $scope on it's own I can inspect it and find the data variable and inspect that but then when I actually log $scope.data in the same log call it is undefined? If $scope is not ready when a watch executes then how am I able to log it and inspect it in the console??

Comment: @Kossel - here's the loadData function - see edit at 00.14

Comment: I dont understand, but you actaully call `$scope.loadData();` after you do console.log :S.

Comment: @Kossel - it looks confusing but really the loadData gets called whenever the user browses another task. When they do that the taskId changes and loadData reloads the page with new data. Does that make sense? $scope.data already exists - it just gets refreshed I think due to inspecting $scope and being able to see it in the console. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix actually;

Simply watched the data property I was interested in, in new $watch and pulled the call to Page.setTitle in to it.

```
$scope.$watch('taskId', function(value) {
    if (value) {
        $scope.loadData();
    }
});

// set browser tab title prefix
$scope.$watch('data.type', function(value) {
    var browserTabTitlePrefix = undefined;
    if(typeof value != 'undefined') {
        browserTabTitlePrefix = $scope.getBrowserTabTitlePrefix(value);
        Page.setTitle(browserTabTitlePrefix + $scope.taskId);
    }
});
```

Now because I'm watching the right property and only calling the sub-function (Page.setTitle) once it is ready I'm golden.

**Alhamdulillaah katheerun**